# How to remove plain text URL from data content column name offilneURL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular7, angular-components

I face issue Cannot hide or remove URL exist as plain text on column name offilneUrl

I already do as link so that no need to plain text URL above

So I need to hide or remove or empty URL plain text above word page link .

```
 <tbody>
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let repcon of ReportControl">

                    <tr *ngFor="let rep of contentBody">

                      <td *ngFor="let coln of headerCols">


                        <span> 

                          {{rep[coln]}}
                        </span>
                        <div *ngIf="coln==repcon.fieldName">


                          <div *ngIf="repcon.columnType==1">

                            <a (click)="goToLink(rep.offilneURL)">page link</a>
                         </div>
                        </div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-container>

                </tbody>
```

I try as below
{{rep.offilneURL || " "}} but it repeated offlineURL with every row

so what i do to solve issue

see image below the text with green color that i need to remove because it .

**post updated**

**structure of content body on ts file**

```
this._displayreport.GetReportDetailsPaging(this.searchData).subscribe((data: any[]) => {

        this.reportdetailslist = data;
       this.headerCols = Object.keys(data[0]);
      this.contentBody = data;

      });
```

data structure for content body :

```
companyName: "Innovasic, Inc."
done: "0"
notImpacted: "0"
notificationDate: "2009-11-12"
offilneURL: "https://source.z2data.com/2019/1/13/8/55/47/351/662203977/21527_SPCN.PDF"
onlineURL: "N/A"
pending: "3"
reportDate: "2020-05-07"
revisionID: "272299243"
teamName: "MFG"
totalCount: 79
```

already have link

[image: plain text surrounded with green color]

**Updated post**

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-4ud1rg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html
```

according to my structure I need to change

```
<span *ngIf="coln != 'onlineURL'"> 
  {{rep[coln]}}
</span>
```

to

```
<span *ngIf="coln != 'repcon.filedName'"> 
      {{rep[coln]}}
    </span>
```

Comment: can you add structure of contentBody ?

Comment: thank you for reply what you mean structure by content body

Comment: I updated post with data for content body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just because:

```
<span>
  {{rep[coln]}}
</span>
```

is still displaying the value regardless so just hide it `if` the column is the url

```
<span *ngIf="repcon.columnType != 1">
  {{rep[coln]}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on the content body structure and logic you shared, you can hide the link as follows.

Based on logic ==>

```html
<span *ngIf="repcon.columnType!=1"> 
  {{rep[coln]}}
</span>
```

I think you are showing the link based on the condition repcon.columnType==1, So check for converse to hide the offline link.

This can be handled in other way as well.

Based on structure ==>

```html
<span *ngIf="coln != 'onlineURL'"> 
  {{rep[coln]}}
</span>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for reply can I use *ngIf="coln!=repcon.fieldname because I try but it not working

Comment: Here is the updated solution - https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-fqavml. Solution is same as described in above answer

Comment: thank you for reply what I need actually is change line 24 to be coln!=repcon.fieldName

Comment: thank you for reply what I need actually is change line 42 to be coln!=repcon.fieldName in place of col!='offilneURL' because this is static but I need it dynamic so please help me I try it more also rep.offilneURL on line 55 it static on component.html I need to be rep[repcon.fieldName to be dynamic this is actually what I need i hope to help me on that

Comment: also any information i will give you to help me on that